# Cutting convex regions into equal diameter and equal least width pieces - 3

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

We add a bit to [Cutting convex regions into equal diameter and equal least width pieces - 2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376672/cutting-convex-regions-into-equal-diameter-and-equal-least-width-pieces-2). There, we asked, for example: If we divide a 2D convex region C into n convex pieces such that the maximum diameter among the pieces is a minimum, will we necessarily also get all pieces with same diameter?

**Questions:**

1. If the maximum diameter among n convex pieces into which C is being divided is to be a minimum, will it automatically guarantee a minimum of the *average diameter* among pieces?

(If minimum diameter among pieces is to be maximized, we have degenerate pieces, although one can also assert that average diameter is then maximized).

One can also ask in the same spirit:

2. If the maximum perimeter among n pieces is to be minimized, will it have any automatic implication on the average perimeter among pieces?
3. If the maximum (minimum) least width among n pieces from C is to be minimized (maximized), will it have any impact on the average least width (The least width of a region is the least distance between any pair of parallel lines that touch the region)?

**Note:** These questions can be asked in reverse direction - whether minimizing the average of a quantity has any impact on its maximum value among pieces. There are also 'cross' versions - whether, say, minimizing the max perimeter among pieces has any impact on the max diameter.

Comment: I just supply a reference in case it’s relevant: John Conway posed what he called the fried potato problem, where you are given a convex body and asked to slice it minimizing the radius of the smallest ball it contains.

Comment: Thanks. The fried potato problem seems to be related to the plank problem. And the plank problem appears related to the question of minimizing among the pieces of the highest least width. So, one part of question 3 above might have a ready answer. But as was mentioned in the previous post in this series (link above), maximizing the minimum least width among pieces might be different.