# Finding the point within a convex n-gon that minimizes the largest angle subtended there by an edge of the n-gon

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

This post records a variant to the question asked in this post: [Finding the point within a convex n-gon that maximizes the least angle subtended there by an edge of the n-gon](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467756/finding-the-point-within-a-convex-n-gon-that-maximizes-the-least-angle-subtended)

- Given a convex n-gon, how does one algorithmically find the interior point that minimizes the maximum angle subtended at the point by an edge of the polygon? Is the optimal point always unique?

Remark 1: It is easy to see that the answers to the present question and the above linked one of trying to maximize the least angle subtended could be different. For example, consider a regular *n*-gon - for which both questions have the centroid as the optimal point - and make it a convex *n+1*-gon by adding a vertex close to one of the *n* pre-existing vertices. Now, for sufficiently large *n*, the interior point minimizing the max subtended angle remains at the centroid but the point maximizing the smallest subtended angle moves towards the newly added short edge.

Remark 2: If the convex point is a triangle, the interior point that minimizes the largest angle subtended there by an edge is unique and is the Steiner point.

Remark 3: Further variants that seek interior point(s) minimizing the *range of angles* subtended there by the edges or the *standard deviation among the angles* subtended there by the edges could also be considered.

Comment: I’d say that, in the notation of the linked post,  the  min max angle is the  maximum  $\theta$ such that the  $n$ disk segments $\{S(e,\theta)\}_{e\in\mathcal E}$  covers the polygon $C$ (denoting here $\mathcal E$ the set of the edges), while the maxmin angle was the maximum  $\theta$ such that the  $n$ disk segments $\{S(e,\theta)\}_{e\in\mathcal E}$ have nonempty intersection.  This I think implies the uniqueness of the minmax point  by an  argument analogous to that for the maxmin point.

Comment: Actually this argument only gives a local uniqueness (hence finiteness). In fact in a rectangle say 1x1000 certainly the center (which is the maxmin point) is certainly not the minmax point, so by simmetry there are (at least) two maxmin points

Comment: Here’s a conjecture:  the max number of max-min angle points  for an $n$-gons is $n-2$

Comment: Guess the basic difference between this question and the earlier one is that here one has to handle intersections of non-convex regions - this might also be the reason why there are multiple optimal points.