# Cutting triangles into triangles with equal longest side

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

This post elaborates on a specific instance of [Cutting convex polygons into triangles of same diameter](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392596/cutting-convex-polygons-into-triangles-of-same-diameter) .

**Question:** For any integer n, can any triangle be cut into n non-degenerate triangles all of same diameter (longest side)? If so, can an algorithm be given?

Note: Some further thoughts are recorded at http://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2023/03/some-questions-on-partitioning-into.html .

Comment: Isn't the diameter of a tirangle just the largest edge?

Comment: yes. made an edit. Thanks